# yii2 вопрос по urlManager

Tags: php, yii2

Можно-ли сделать примерно такое правило `'houses' => 'site/sell?type=house'` ?

Что было бы еквивалентно - 
`http://standart.dev/houses`   ->   `http://standart.dev/site/sell?type=house`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'rules' => [
     ['pattern' => 'houses', 'route' => 'site/sell', 'defaults' => ['type' => 'house']]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Для этого в конфиг такой код:

```
...
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
         ...
         'houses' => '/site/sell',
         ...   
    ],
],
...
```

а в SiteController такой:

```
public function actionSell($type = 'house') {...}
```